# React Native FlatList Not Re-Rendering after Asyncronous operation

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

I have an async function like this:

```
getDeals() {
  if(this.props.user) {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    this.setState({deals: []});

    var parameters = {
      zip: this.props.user.zip,
      sort: 'All',
      category: this.props.selectedCategory,
      company: this.props.user.company,
      page: null,
      user: this.props.user,
      search: null
    }

    axios.post(`${constants.api}/grab-deals/`, parameters)
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({totalDeals: response.data.length});
      this.setState({deals: response.data, loading: false, refreshing: false});
      this.forceUpdate();
    })
  }
}
```

And a FlatList component Like this:

```
<FlatList data={this.state.deals} style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}} extraData={this.state} keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor} renderItem={this.renderDeal.bind(this)} />
```

Here is the keyextractor:
`keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;`

When I call `this.getDeals()` the first time it works great.  However when I call it a second time the axios call get's all of the correct data, but the flat list still keeps old data (it doesn't remove items that aren't in the new call).

How do I get the FlatList to always reflect the returned data?

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.getDeals()` in `componentWillUpdate()` and update props?

Comment: please add more details

Answer (score 0):

I believe you confussing what props and state is for. Basically state is used for things that could change during the lifecycle of the component and props are kept immutable. I use them for behavior.

Unless you are changing the parameters for the getDeals function on the second call, see that all of the properties are based on the props, which are not always updated.

RN has a method called componentWillUpdate that is triggered with the new props which you can then be used to update the component itself. If you want to keep using props in your getDeals method, you will need to check if the props have changed (this happens when the parent updates the child with new props) and then trigger again the data fetch.

If this does not help, please post more code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) you need to set the `state.selected` value

> By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList
>   itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting
>   this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items
>   because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not
>   show any changes.